# Extract constant value from python by boost python

Tags: python, c++, boost

codes of python(which work)

```
import ldap,ldif

l = ldap.initialize('ldaps://RIO-PC:636')
l.set_option(ldap.OPT_TIMEOUT);
```

I want to extract the constant value of ldap.OPT_TIMEOUT, but how to?

```
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/python.hpp>

int main()
{
    namespace bp = boost::python;
    try{
        Py_Initialize();
        bp::object main_module = bp::import("__main__");
        bp::import("ldap");
        bp::import("ldif");
        bp::object main_namespace = main_module.attr("__dict__");

        bp::exec("import ldap,ldif\n"
                 "l = ldap.initialize('ldaps://RIO-PC')\n",
             main_namespace);

        boost::python::object ldap = boost::python::extract<boost::python::object>(main_namespace["l"]);
        ldap.attr("OPT_TIMEOUT"); //this line will throw exception
    }catch(boost::python::error_already_set const &){               
        PyErr_Print();
        PyErr_Clear();
    }
}
```

the error message is

**AttributeError: SimpleLDAPObject has no attribute 'OPT_TIMEOUT'**

environment

compiler : vc2008
boost version : 1.55_0
os : win7 64bits(x64)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your C++ code is trying to extract `l.OPT_TIMEOUT`, not `ldap.OPT_TIMEOUT`. Try

```
    bp::object ldap_module = bp::import("ldap");
    ldap_module.attr("OPT_TIMEOUT");
```